# Prompting for input until 2 blank lines are given

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

I need to prompt a user for input until 2 blank lines are given in a row, please note that the input read may have blank lines in it for clarity purposes, I will need two blank lines given back to back before it breaks.

So far I've come up with this:

```
def gather_intel():
    done = False
    while done is False:
        data = raw_input("Copy and paste the work log: ")
        if data is None:
            done = True
```

How ever this will end as soon as a single blank line is given, I've also tried adding another `while` loop to it:

```
def gather_intel():
    done = False
    while done is False:
        data = raw_input("Copy and paste the work log: ")
        while data != "" + "\n" + "":
            data = raw_input("Copy and paste the work log: ")
            if data == "" + "\n" + "":
                done = True
```

However this one is an infinite loop and will never end. How can I prompt a user for input, until there are two blank lines given to the input back to back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
number_of_empty_responses = 0
while True:
    data = raw_input("Copy and paste the work log: ")
    if data == "":
        number_of_empty_responses += 1
        if number_of_empty_responses == 2:
            break
    else:
        number_of_empty_responses = 0
        pass # Received data, perform work.
```

Comment: 2 blank lines in a row, sorry for not specifying

Comment: As in, the user hits the "Enter" key on two successive prompts?

Comment: Yes sir, that's exactly it

Comment: The above code will break when exactly two blank lines are given, if the data read has blank lines in it for clarity..

Comment: Then you'll need to clarify in your question as it is ambiguous as to what you're exactly attempting to achieve.

Comment: I reconfigured it a little bit and it worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

For future me or somebody else. The `input` until 2 conscutive newline characters:

```
def handy_input(prompt='> '):
    'An `input` with 2 newline characters ending.'

    all_input_strings = ''

    # prompt the user for input
    given_input = input(prompt)
    all_input_strings += given_input
    # and handle the two newline ending                                                                                                           
    while given_input:
        # if previous input is not empty prompt again
        given_input = input('')
        all_input_strings += '\n' + given_input

    return all_input_strings
```

And the answer to the question with 2 empty lines:

```
def empty_lines_input(prompt='> ', n_lines=2):
    'An `input` with `n_lines` empty line ending.'

    all_input_strings = ''

    # prompt the user for input
    given_input = input(prompt)
    all_input_strings += given_input
    # and handle the two newline ending                                                                                                           
    while n_lines>0:
        # if previous input is not empty prompt again
        given_input = input('')
        all_input_strings += '\n' + given_input
        # check if it was an empty line
        if not given_input:
            n_lines -= 1
        else:
            n_lines = 2

    return all_input_strings
```